# View/Constant function benchmarks

Tags: solidity, mapping, benchmark

Given I want to return a `mapping` from a function, which is impossible, therefore I return each of the mapping's item in a function by a corresponding `ID`, like this answer suggests :
[How to return a mapping type?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11926/how-to-return-a-mapping-type)

Given I want to iterate over all existing IDs in a `mapping` in order to retrieve all user assets, how long does it take to call a single iteration ?

Comment: You cannot iterate over a mapping in solidity, unless you hold the key types in a collection such as an array and access their corresponding value in the mapping one-by-one.

Comment: @HarryWright This is exactly what I asked, one-by-one, I know my IDs will be, say, 1-10, because say I want to delete from my mapping, I need to delete from the array, and that is inefficient.

Comment: As a followup of my previous question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35790/efficient-approach-to-delete-element-from-array-in-solidity